# vb.net how to pause while loop until user clicks button?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I am using while loop to pull data from access database.
After each run I want loop to pause till user clicks button in the form.

How can I do this?

Comment: Kindly be elaborate.

Comment: add more details..button means button inside same form  or whatever?

Comment: Smelly code... Running a while loop on the ui thread waiting for user input, doesn't sound right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the button set a flag value that a second while loop checks before letting the main loop proceed. Very simplified example below.

```
    Private Sub GetData()

    Dim i As Integer

    ' Loop that fetches data from Access, probably
    ' based on record count or similar
    While i < 1000

        btnGetMoreData.Enabled = False
        getMoreData = False

        ' code here for retrieving data
        Debug.Print("I am retrieving data")

        btnGetMoreData.Enabled = True
        While getMoreData = False
            ' process messages from UI
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While

    End While

End Sub

Private Sub btnGetMoreData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetMoreData.Click

    getMoreData = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Do While True` works as well, I is a bit mysterious. However, you can set a worst case timeout value compared e.g. `Do While Now() < dtTimeout` so your program doesn't loop forever.

Comment: If its not good to pause while loop.. can you suggest anything else for achieving it. What I am doing is I am pulling questions from data base one by one, user answers then next question gets displayed

Comment: One possibility is to use a SQLDataReader and call Next when the user clicks a button. "Next" will move to the next record. You could modify this example to do what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157143/using-sqldatareader-instead-of-recordset Another possibility is to retrieve a record from the database directly each time the user clicks the button.