# How can I run SQL Server using VB as a ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic, ado.net

I'm currently using Classic ASP in order to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database using the following code:

```
dim  Example_DatabaseName

Example_DatabaseName = "driver={SQL Server};server=(local);use uid=sa;pwd=; OR Trusted_Connection=yes;database=NameOFDatabaseTesting"

Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs1.Open mySQL1, Example_DatabaseName

Do While Not rs1.eof
response.write rs1("NameOfPerson") & "<br>"
rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.close
set rs1 = Nothing
```

This code will not work with ASPX, but it's working just fine with Classic ASP on a localhost IIS. I've researched online I'm getting the all different error and that leads me even more confusing...

I would like to have your help/advice how to do this for ASPX using VB script - however, I'm not very familiar with ASP.net - I'm just trying to teach myself how to use it.

---

I'm getting error message:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
```

Above error message is for:

```
Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just let you know now it's working just fine - Thanks to all of you who point out few idea :)

This is whole page just in case if anyone who face similar issue as me:

```
<%@ Page language="vb" debug="true" %>

<% @Import Namespace="System" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

    <%

    Dim sConnection As String = "Server=(local);Database=NameOfDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
            Con.Open()
            Using Com As New SqlCommand("Select Name From Test_Table", Con)
                Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
                    If RDR.HasRows Then
                        Do While RDR.Read

                            response.write (RDR("Name").ToString)

                        Loop
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
            Con.Close()
       End Using

    %>
```

Indeed those script is very big different from Classic ASP phew!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use VBScript as a scripting language in an aspx (asp.net) file.  You can use VB.net, which is a similar language, but by no means identical.

If you want to use COM objects (which include ado connections and recordsets) in an asp.net page then you need to add `aspcompat=true` to the page directive, eg

```
<%@ Page AspCompat="true" Language="VB" %>
```

The code you have provided, converted into VB.net would look like this

```
dim  Example_DatabaseName

Example_DatabaseName = "driver={SQL Server};server=(local);use uid=sa;pwd=; OR Trusted_Connection=yes;database=NameOFDatabaseTesting"

rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs1.Open (mySQL1, Example_DatabaseName)

Do While Not rs1.eof
response.write rs1("NameOfPerson").value & "<br>"
rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.close
rs1 = Nothing
```

Note that VB.net doesn't use `Let` or `Set`, and the use of `.value` after your recordset item.

One caveat I should add.  This offers the shortest path to adapting your existing code for use in an ASPX page, which is what I'm assuming you're looking for.  ASP.net has better methods of connecting to a database than ado recordset objects, but the code is so different that you'll probably need to rewrite it entirely, in which case I'd recommend forgetting about VB.net and using C#, for which you'll be able to find a lot more examples and tutorials

Comment: well to be honest I'm more used to classic asp with VBscript mostly, i know it's old and outdated. That's why I'm learning all over again using ASP.net using VB coding structure. 

if you think C# is the best route then I will have to re-learn the whole thing all over again !

Comment: While you can use JScript for Classic ASP  just about everyone does use VBScript.  It's the same with VB.net and C# in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Adapted directly from here [Using SQLDataReader instead of recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157143/using-sqldatareader-instead-of-recordset)

```
Dim sConnection As String = "driver={SQL Server};server=(local);use uid=sa;pwd=; OR Trusted_Connection=yes;database=NameOFDatabaseTesting"
    Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        Con.Open()
        Using Com As New SqlCommand("Select NameOfPerson From Person", Con)
            Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
                If RDR.HasRows Then
                    Do While RDR.Read
                        Response.Write( RDR.Item("NameOfPerson ").ToString())
                    Loop
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting error for this line:                                                                        Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)

Comment: Even if you write something in the response, the default behaviour for an aspx is to append html page markup into the response as well. You probably need to call response End, but I haven't tested your code.

Comment: @Jedi-78 - If you're getting an error, **tell us what it is!!**  Don't make us guess!